# How can I print an associative array as a matrix

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm creating 2 associative arrays in which I put random values from 0 to 30, and after that I want to print then as a matrix. Is there a way I can do that?

Here is my code:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
    TYPE MyTab IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10);
    mat1 MyTab;
    mat2 MyTab;
    v_n NUMBER(2);
    v_m NUMBER(2);
    v_nr NUMBER(3);
    v_dim NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
   v_n := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
   v_m := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
   v_nr := 1;
   v_dim := v_n*v_m;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_n||'    '||v_m);
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat1(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;
   v_nr := 1;
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat2(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mat1(i));    
    END LOOP; 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mat2(i));    
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: What do you want inside the matrix? Do you want to multiply the values and display?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to multiply the matrix mat1 with matrix mat2 and then to display the result as a matrix .. but i still have a long way to go until then and i'm taking it with baby steps

Comment: Oh sorry I just understood you wanted to display your **random size** matrixes... Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just understood there are 2 matrixes, `mat1` and `mat2`, which have various size (but both have same dimensions).
Here is how to display them:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
    TYPE MyTab IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY  pls_integer;
    mat1 MyTab;
    mat2 MyTab;
    v_n pls_integer;
    v_m pls_integer;
    v_nr pls_integer;
    v_dim pls_integer;
BEGIN
   v_n := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
   v_m := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
   if (v_n > v_m) then
       -- switch values for V_m to be the biggest dim
       v_nr:=v_n;
       v_n:=v_m;
       v_m:=v_nr;
   end if;

   v_nr := 1;
   v_dim := v_n*v_m;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_n||'    '||v_m);
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat1(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;
   v_nr := 1;
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat2(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MATRIX1');      
   FOR i in 1 ..v_n LOOP
       FOR j in 1 ..v_m LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' - '|| rpad(mat1((j-1)*v_n + i), 4));               
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MATRIX2');      
   FOR i in 1 ..v_n LOOP
       FOR j in 1 ..v_m LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' - '|| rpad(mat2((j-1)*v_n + i), 4));               
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

I changed the types to `pls_integer` which looks more simple. Then keep in mind that I put the matrices in the good form where they can be multiplied (swith `v_n`and `v_m` in the loops, and added formatting to understand what happens.

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE MyTab IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY  pls_integer;
    mat1 MyTab;
    mat2 MyTab;
    v_n pls_integer;
    v_m pls_integer;
    v_nr pls_integer;
    v_dim pls_integer;
    idx pls_integer;
    idx1 pls_integer;
    idx2 pls_integer;
    v_p number;
BEGIN
   v_n := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
   v_m := round(dbms_random.value(2,5));
--   v_n := 2; -- formating works better with 2 and 3
--   v_m := 3;
   v_nr := 1;
   v_dim := v_n*v_m;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_n||'    '||v_m);
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat1(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;
   v_nr := 1;
   FOR i in 1 ..v_dim LOOP
       mat2(v_nr) := round(dbms_random.value(0,30));
       v_nr := v_nr+1;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MATRIX1:a');      
   FOR i in 1 ..v_n LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('        ..................    ');
       FOR j in 1 ..v_m LOOP
           idx:=(j-1)*v_n + i;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' |'||j||','||i||'a['||idx||']'|| rpad(mat1(idx), 4));               
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MATRIX2:b');      
   FOR i in 1 ..v_m LOOP
       FOR j in 1 ..v_n LOOP
           idx:=(j-1)*v_m + i;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' |'||j||','||i||'b['||idx||']'|| rpad(mat2(idx), 4));               
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
   END LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('product: a x b');      
   FOR L in 1 ..v_m LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ---------------------------');
       FOR K in 1 ..v_m LOOP
           v_p:=0;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' | ');
           FOR j in 1 ..v_n LOOP
               idx1 := j + (K-1)*v_n;
               idx2 := (j-1)*v_m + L;
               v_p := v_p + mat1(idx1) *  mat2(idx2) ;
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('a['||idx1||']b['||idx2||']+');
           END LOOP;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('->'|| rpad(v_p, 4));               
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END LOOP; 

END;
/
```

Comment: if you used that FOR i and FOR j to display the matrix can i use something like this to do the multiplications between the 2 matrices?
`v_p := 1;
   FOR i IN 1 ..v_n*v_n LOOP
      mat3(i) := 0;
   END LOOP;
   FOR i IN 1 ..v_n LOOP
     FOR j IN 1 ..v_n LOOP
       FOR k IN 1 ..v_m LOOP
         mat3(v_p) := mat3(v_p)+mat1(k*i)*mat2(j*k);
       END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
     v_p := v_p+1;
   END LOOP;`

Comment: Yes of course you can. But indexing values and modifying values are two thing different. We use `i * j` because it is the way you choose to store the data. If you want to multiply the values together, you need to work on compatible matrices, i.e. `mat1` will be indexed with  `i*j` and `mat2` with `j*i`.

Comment: so it is a difference between `mat2(i*j)` and `mat2(j*i)`?

Comment: No, I mean the dimensions of the matrices are not known. So the resulting product size is also unknown.

Comment: now I think I get it..when i do the indexing I have to index mat1 as i*j and mat2 as j*i, and then if i use that code I could do the multiplication..am I right or I still don't get it?

Comment: Well this is pretty difficult to explain with words. It is possible to do it, but it might not be the easiest. There probably exist Oracle Libraries to do matrices multiplications. For the beauty of algorithm I will try though.

Comment: i think java and c are more easy languages but i really want to try to understand oracle as well and this is giving me a headache :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use Matrix for calculation or logging?

It is quite difficult to logging with Matrix. I don't think it is a good way. If you insist, here's the code.

```
FOR i in 1 ..v_n LOOP
   FOR j in 1 ..v_m LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( mat.at<double>(i,j));
```

Comment: i want to use Matrix for calculation..my ultimate goal is to multiply the matrix mat1 with matrix mat2 and then to display the result as a matrix